# NetBeans 6.9.1 fails to see svn configuration for SSHFS mounted drive

Tags: svn, netbeans, sshfs

I'm using NetBeans 6.9.1 with the Python package on OS X 10.6.8 for a project I've mounted using FUSE for OS X and MacFusion.

Initially, when checking out the project from subversion, I'm able to commit and update as I wish. However - when I restart NetBeans, it fails to see the svn configuration for the project.
The project Subversion context menu is empty.

When I try to commit from Team -> Subversion -> Commit (yes, that option is still there), it yields this error: Cannot determine repositoryRootUrl for selected context:
/Volumes/mounted/project/root/files

I've already tried the Macfusion option "-o workaround=rename" as per the resolved svn issues on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1065308 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the work around is quite easy... Make sure the SSHFS drive is mounted before starting NetBeans, if your project is still loaded in NetBeans.